# How do I transpose only half of my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, transpose

I have a dataframe like this

| Date | Region | Parameter | Area | Mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `2005-01-01` | NSW | Precipitation | 8.002343e+05 | 0.044274 |
| `2005-01-01` | NSW | RelativeHumidity | 8.002343e+05 | 36.355567 |
| `2005-01-01` | NSW | SoilWaterContent | 8.002343e+05 | 0.170931 |
| `2005-01-01` | NSW | SolarRadiation | 8.002343e+05 | 26.749389 |
| `2005-01-01` | NSW | Temperature | 8.002343e+05 | 27.341182 |

I want to transpose it into this

| Date | Region | PrecipitationArea | RelativeHumidityArea | SoilWaterContentArea | SolarRadiationArea | TemperatureArea | PrecipitationMean | RelativeHumidityMean | SoilWaterContentMean | SolarRadiationMean | TemperatureMean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-01-01 | NSW | 8.002343e+05 | 8.002343e+05 | 8.002343e+05 | 8.002343e+05 | 8.002343e+05 | 0.044274 | 36.355567 | 0.170931 | 26.749389 | 27.341182 |

Should I be using pivot or melt in this situation?